# C# Why can't I implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, syntax, syntax-error

I am trying to figure out how to solve the error as stated in the title, which occurs on the bold line within this snippet:

```
     while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string row = textIn.ReadLine();
            string[] columns = row.Split('|');
            StudentClass studentList = new StudentClass();
            studentList.Name = columns[0];
            **studentList.Scores =  columns[1];**
            students.Add(studentList);
        }
```

The previous line of code loads the names just fine since it is not a List within the class I have created, but "Scores" is within a list, however. What modifications would I need to do? These values are supposed to be displayed within a textbox from a text file upon loading the application.

Here is the class in which "Scores" is in (I have highlighted it):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNameSpace
{

//set the class to public
 public class StudentClass
{

    public StudentClass()
    {
        this.Scores = new List<int>();


    }

    public StudentClass (string Name, List<int> Scores)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Scores = Scores;
    }



    public string Name
    { get;
      set;
    }

    //initializes the scores
    **public List<int> Scores
    { get;
      set;
    }**


    public override string ToString()
    {
        string names = this.Name;

        foreach (int myScore in Scores)
        { names += "|" + myScore.ToString();

        }
        return names;
    }


    public int GetScoreTotal()
    {
        int sum = 0;

        foreach (int score in Scores)
        { sum += score;


        }

        return sum;

    }

    public int GetScoreCount()
    { return Scores.Count;

    }

    public void addScore(int Score)
    {
        Scores.Add(Score);


    }



}
}
```

Comment: The program doesn't know how you expect a string to be converted into a list of ints. If it's in some delimited format, you will need to parse that separately before turning it into a list of ints.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain why you think you _should_ be able to implicitly convert a `string` value to an instance of `List<int>`. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do, and provide a precise explanation of what that code is expected to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assign a string containing a sequence of numbers to a property of type `List<int>`.

You need to split the string into seperate numbers, then parse these substrings to get the integers they represent.

E.g.

```
    var text = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
    var numerals = text.Split(' ');
    var numbers = numerals.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

I.e. in your code replace:

```
studentList.Scores =  columns[1];
```

with:

```
studentList.Scores = columns[1].Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

(Or your own multi-line, more readable/debugable equivalent.)

You'll need to modify the parameter passed to `Split()` according to how the scores are formatted in your column.

You'll also need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top if you don't already have it.

Comment: I would like something like this within a listbox which is read from a text file:
 John Doe |97|71|83|
Daniel Lopez |99|93|97|
Jane Doe |100|100|99|

However I get this:

 John Doe |97
Daniel Lopez |99
Jane Doe |100

And if I add an extra column variable it will just replace the scores above with the next set of scores to the right of it. Like so:

John Doe |71
Daniel Lopez |93
Jane Doe |100

Comment: @ChocolateSnow That sounds like a new question, so you should post it as a new question. Also, try to present your problem as clearly as possible, as your comment is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the question goes, how would the compiler ever know how to convert the string to a list, when there could be so many string representations of a list.    If it was to do this it would be an incredibly slow operation.

**Fix**
To fix your code you could replace your loop with this.

```
while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
{
    string row = textIn.ReadLine();
    StudentClass studentList = new StudentClass();
    int index = row.IndexOf("|");

    //checking that there were some scores
    if (index < 0) {
        studentList.Name = row;
        continue;
    }

    studentList.Name = row.Substring(0, index);
    studentList.Scores =  row.Substring(index + 1).Split('|').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
    students.Add(studentList);
}
```

There are however a number of problems even with this fix.
For one if you were to add another list delimited by '|' it would become increasingly hard for you to parse using this kind of approach.

I suggest instead that you look at serializing your class(es) with something a little more powerful and generic like Json.Net.

Hope this helps.